# Openerp / Odoo - Install modules without redirecting to odoo.com

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

How can I install a new module in my Openerp 7, considering I have 4 users and I do not have USD35,00 per month to pay the official support? I heard there is a command line that would let me install a module. Is it true?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are mutliple ways to install Odoo, or not install it at all, depending on the intended use case.

This documents attempts to describe most of the installation options.

**Demo**

the simplest "installation", only suitable for getting a quick feel for Odoo or trying something out

**SaaS**

trivial to start with and fully managed and migrated by Odoo S.A., can be used to both test Odoo and use it for your business, but restricts the flexibility of the system somewhat (check: no custom modules? what else?).

Can be used for both testing Odoo and long-term "production" use.

**Packaged installers**

simple to get started, allows more flexibility in hosting and deploying the system and greater control over where data is stored. The maintenance burden is shifted to the user.

Suitable for testing Odoo, developing modules and can be used for long-term production use with additional deployment and maintenance work.

**Source Install**

harder to get started than Packaged installers, provides even greater flexibility: packaged installers don't generally allow multiple running Odoo versions on the same system, and don't provide easy source access to Odoo itself.

Good for developing modules, can be used as base for production deployment.

The source code can be obtained by downloading a tarball or using git. Using git makes it easier to update, switch between multiple versions (including the current development version) or contribute.

**docker image**

if you usually use docker for development or deployment, an official docker base image is available, see the image's help document for more information

you can refer this link

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/setup/install.html

Answer (score 0):

Hello Eduardo Marzolla,

Yes,It is possible to install our module with the command prompt you need to follow the below steps to install our module with the command prompt.

**1.Go To the your workspace with the use of command prompt to Odoo Server :**

Using cd command just go with at the server directory where  our server file is located.

```
best@ubuntu:~$ cd workspace/dynaweld/server/
```

**2.Go To the your workspace with the use of command prompt to Odoo Server :**

**OpenERP 7.0 :**

```
./openerp-server --addons-path=../addons/,../web/addons/ -i <your module name> -d <your database name>
```

**Odoo 8.0 or later :**

```
./openerp-server  -i <your module name> -d <your database name>
```

hear we are using **-i** options to install your module name  with to particular database **-d** options.

I hope my answer may  helpful for you :)